# MVC4: HTML5 boolean attributes rendered with True/False value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

I'm trying to render a radiobutton with some boolean attributes (required and disabled) using:

```
@Html.RadioButton("radio-name","false", new { id="test", required=Model.BooleanValue})
```

and

```
<input type="radio" name="radio-name" id="radio-name-no" value="false" class="radio" @if (!Model.BooleanValue) { <text>required</text> } disabled="@Model.BooleanValue" />
```

But the output is this:

```
<input id="test" name="radio-name" required="False" value="false" type="radio">
```

and

```
<input name="radio-name" id="radio-name-no" value="false" class="radio" disabled="True" type="radio">
```

MVC4 should render the boolean attributes as per HTML5 specs, so why it's outputting `disabled="True"` (or `False`) instead of `disabled="disabled"` or `disabled` (or nothing at all if the `BooleanValue` property is `false`)?

Comment: Because your telling it to by using `disabled="@Model.BooleanValue"` - but what are you wanting to do here. `disabled="true"` and `disabled="false"` (or `disabled="disabled"` or just `disabled`) are all identical - its the presence of the attribute which determines if its disabled or not. You need to conditionally add the attribute.

Comment: Razor2 should, if the HTML5 attribute is a boolean attribute, automatically render it as `disabled` (or `disabled=disabled`) instead of `disabled="True"`, and don't render it at all if the Model's property is false or null. It seems like in my case it does a ToString() and directly assigning the boolean's value to the attribute.

Comment: Not in the first case (by adding `htmlAttributes` using `new { ... }` (conditional attributes do not apply then). And the 2nd case does work and will generate `disabled="disabled" if the property is `true` and omit it if `false` - I can only assume your not using Razor2

Comment: Thanks for the clarification for the first case.For the second one I've double checked the Razor dll version and it's 2.0.20710.0

Comment: Works just fine for me in MVC-5 (cant test in MVC-4 at the moment)

Comment: Are you sure you have shown the correct code - your 2nd example html has `checked="True"` but you have not added that attribute so it could not have been added based on your code

Comment: @StephenMuecke yeah, I was doing some tests and deleted the checked attribute (will update the question, thanks).

Funny thing: just tried adding the boolean value to the class attribute with `class=Model.BooleanValue` and works as expected (hiding the `class` attribute when the value is `false`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159041/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-user1527576).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include conditionally rendered attributes like this:

```html
<input 
    type="radio"
    required="@(!Model.BooleanValue)"
    disabled="@Model.BooleanValue" />
```

The solution was pretty strange. While doing some tests, I put an @if in the HTML input tag. This if was used to show the `required` attribute. After this @if, I put the `disabled="@Model.BooleanValue"` attribute.

It seems that this order disrupted the expected behaviour. Placing the `disabled` attribute before the @if solved the problem (later I have deleted the @if and converted it to `required="@(!Model.BooleanValue)"`).